# Xamarin native shared, pass data to another page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to pass date (Username) from the `LoginPage` to the `HomePage` which is opened by a button, I know that I need to add some code in the button function.

```
namespace UniLife.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "UniLife.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        public Task NavigationPage { get; private set; }

        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LogInPage);

            // Get our buttons and TextBoxes from the layout resource
            Button LoginButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.LoginButton);
            EditText Username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.UsernameTextBox);
            EditText Password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PasswordTextBox);

            // Set a function to the button on click
            LoginButton.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomePage);
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("extrastuff", extraStuff);
        StartActivity(intent);
```

This is what you are looking for.

You can retrieve the extra in your HomeActivity by doing:

```
this.Intent.GetStringExtra("extraStuff");
```

Comment: Do I store that line in the HomeActivity as a string and then use it ?

Comment: @TareqAl-Abbar Nope! the first piece of code you put in the MainActivity. You're creating an Intent of type HomeActivity and set extra string on that. Then you Start the HomeActivity by StartActivity(intent). In your HomeActivity screen in the OnCreate for example you can then retrieve the extra string

Answer (score 0):

You should use StartActivity and set preferences.

Login Page button click Code

```
   ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
        editor.PutString("Var1", "Val1");
        editor.PutString("Var2", "val2");


        editor.Apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomePageActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
```

Then in the Home Page code's OnCreate method

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    var val1 = prefs.GetString("var1", "0")
```

and so on..